# Jquery | how to add var to ajax url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure how to do this,
my vars are:

```
var username = "test";
var username = "1234";
```

I want to include those 2 vars in the url request

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://myurl.com/index.php?username=(+username+)&password=(+password+)",
```

Comment: Learn to concatenate Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can use ES6 feature called [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (` `)  (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes. Template literals can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (${expression}).

```js
var username = "test";

var password = "1234";

var url = `http://myurl.com/index.php?username=${username}&password=${password}`;
console.log(url);
```

So your code looks like

```
var username = "test";
var username = "1234";
$.ajax({
    url: `http://myurl.com/index.php?username=${username}&password=${password}`,
```

Comment: after var username and password, line 18

Answer (score 3):

```
"http://myurl.com/index.php?username="+ username +"&password="+ password
```

Put the variables outside the string when concatenating them.

Comment: can you check my jsfiddle please? http://jsfiddle.net/3Lqsx/7447/ its not getting the var

Comment: Also encode the username and password `encodeURIComponent(username)`; it may mitigate some injection attacks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Declare your username and password outside the .each function so it will be available to the ajax function.

Comment: More info on variable scope here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_scope

Comment: Thank you chris, i did it and its work. but now its start some other loop problem, the request i sent twice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50617330/how-to-arrange-the-next-ajax

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ES6 template literals like this is the best way :

```
url:`http://myurl.com/index.phpusername=${username}&password=${password}`,
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi please check the below answer:

```
var username = "test";
var username = "1234";
$.ajax({ url: "http://myurl.com/index.php?username="+username+"&password="+password+"});
```