# How to arrange the next AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Once I click on start it sends the request few times, how can I fix it, please?

[GIF](https://gyazo.com/d291f7850e0730e0667f3b61209ae02a)

The request should be sent one time.

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lqsx/7458/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jsonp2").click(function () {

        $val = $('#d').html();
        var number = ($val);
        var array = $('#test').val().split("\n");
        $.each(array, function (i) {
            var ok = (array[number]);
            var arr = ok.split(":");
            var username = (arr[0]);
            var password = (arr[1]);

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#jsonp2").click(function () {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://linux-app.tv:8080/player_api.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&type=m3u",
                        success: function (response) {
                            var data = response.user_info;
                            if (data.status.match("Active")) {
                                $(".aprovadas").append("Username:" + data.username + "\npassword:" + data.password + "\nstatus:" + data.status);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You have 2 (document).ready and 2 button clicks events for #jsonp2.

Comment: Yes, I noticed and used the code below. But it still sends twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had ajax call inside the `$.each` which was sending it twice earlier

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lqsx/7461/)

Comment: Thank you very much:) its perfect now

Comment: Pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 1):

First you some redundant code like `$(document).ready(function() {` OR `$("#jsonp2").click(function() {` . so remove it.

Second you are always passing `number` to `array`, It should be `i`.

Check the updated code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jsonp2").click(function() {

        $val = $('#d').html();
        var number = ($val);
                console.log(number)
        var array = $('#test').val().split("\n");
        $.each(array, function(i) {
            var ok = (array[i]);
            var arr = ok.split(":");
            var username = (arr[0]);
            var password = (arr[1]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://linux-app.tv:8080/player_api.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&type=m3u",
                success: function(response) {
                    var data = response.user_info;

                    if (data.status.match("Active")) {
                        $(".aprovadas").append("Username:" + data.username + "\npassword:" + data.password + "\nstatus:" + data.status);
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lqsx/7462/)